# How to enable JVM remote debugger for executors?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to setup the JVM remote debugger to set a breakpoint on the kafka consumer to identify an issue connecting to a Kafka broker.

I've checked out 2.2 ...

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/spark
git checkout branch-2.2
```

I've set up the spark root pom.xml scala maven plugin to generate debug symbols:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      ...
        <javacGenerateDebugSymbols>true</javacGenerateDebugSymbols>
        ...
```

... I then built with ...

```
mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

... and run with ...

```
./bin/spark-shell --master local[1] \
  --jars external/kafka-0-10-sql/target/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar,external/kafka-0-10-assembly/target/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=localhost:5005,suspend=y" \
  --num-executors 1 \
  --executor-cores 1
```

I set up a Remote debug configuration in IntelliJ ...

- **Transport:** socket
- **Debugger Mode:** Listen
- **Port:** 5005

I've added a breakpoint on `org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider` ...

I've also updated the logging statement to ensure that this code is getting run:

[image]

After the spark-shell starts, I run the following ...

```
sc.setLogLevel("DEBUG")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StreamingRetailTransactions").config("master", "local").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.readStream.
                format("kafka").
                option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "0.0.0.0:9093").
                option("subscribe", "transactions_load").
                option("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT").
                option("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN").
                option("auto.offset.reset","earliest").
                option("group.id", System.currentTimeMillis).
                load()

val query = df.writeStream.format("console").start()
```

The log output shows my update debug statement.  It also shows the code being run on the executor.  However, my breakpoint is not triggered ...

```
8/01/17 18:28:33 DEBUG KafkaSourceProvider: executor: ** Set 
key.deserializer to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer, earlier value:
```

You can see that IntelliJ is listening for a connection:

[image]

I'm obviously missing a step somewhere - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had to add the debug options to the driver as well:

```
./bin/spark-shell --master local[1] \
  --jars external/kafka-0-10-sql/target/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar,external/kafka-0-10-assembly/target/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=localhost:5005,suspend=y"   \
  --num-executors 1 \
  --executor-cores 1 \
  --driver-java-options -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=5005
```

Comment: You had to add the options to the driver because you use local mode (`local[1]`) and so the driver is the only executor available. Please use `local[*]` instead which makes sure that you've got enough CPUs to do processing.